# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

When I use the method `slice()`, I get : **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')"**. Whereas when I remove the method `slice()`, the Pokemon cards are rendered as a list. Unfortunately, I do need this method to create a pagination. Is there any equivalent to `slice()` ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

import PokemonCard from './PokemonCard';


export default class PokemonList extends Component {
    state = {
        url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0",
        pokemon: null, // on créé un objet (qui va devenir un tableau) pokemon null c'est où on va enregistrer le json
        pageNumber: 1,
        pokemonsPerPage: 16
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const res = await axios.get(this.state.url); 
        console.log(res.data['results']);
        this.setState({pokemon: res.data['results']}); 
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.pokemon);

        const pagesVisited = this.state.pageNumber * this.state.pokemonsPerPage;

        const displayUsers = this.state.pokemon
            .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + this.state.pokemonsPerPage)
            .map((pokemon) => {
                return (
                    <PokemonCard 
                        key={pokemon.name} 
                        name={pokemon.name} 
                        url={pokemon.url} 
                    /> 
                )
            })
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.state.pokemon ? ( 
                    <div className='row'>
                        {displayUsers}
                    </div>
                ) : (<h2>Loading Pokemon</h2>)} 
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of `this.state.pokemon`? Hint: It's not an `Array` and therefor has no `.slice` method available. Deriving from your error, it is `null` (at least initially) and you cannot call `.slice` on `null`. What you need is to guard against `null`, for example with an `if`-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your initial state you set 'pokemon' to null. Method slice() does not exist on 'null'. You should either set 'pokemon' to an empty array in the initial state or add a check that it is not null before slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set initial state of Pokemon to an empty array

Like this:

```js
    state = {
        url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0",
        pokemon: [], // empty Pokemon array
        pageNumber: 1,
        pokemonsPerPage: 16
    };
```